# Icon fade to text seems to face issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a fade into text on my icons for my navigation bar and got most of it working correctly. However, I'm attempting to output different text for each icon. It seems to output "home" for each icon rather than what I have set. any help?

**Live Example**
https://gyazo.com/1b9cd57d4b208686fe2c205eff9e21f8

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav_bar">

<a class="logo" rel="index" href="input.url">
  <img src="assets/img/logo.png">
  <img src="assets/img/logo.png">
</a>


<nav class=" en">
  <li><a rel="index" href="input.url" class="home-link active"><i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i></a></li>
  <li><a rel="about" href="input.url" class=""><i class="fas fa-user-alt fa-2x"></i></a></li>
  <li>
    <a rel="skills" href="input.url" class=""><i class="fas fa-cog fa-2x"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a rel="gallery" href="input.url" class=""><i class="fas fa-eye fa-2x"></i></a></li>
  <li><a rel="contact" href="input.url" class=""><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
  </li>

</nav>

<li><a href="input.url" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="input.url" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="input.url" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="input.url" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>

<a id="mobile-link" href="input.url"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

**CSS**
Won't let me paste in for some reason so he's the paste bin. Willing to pay anyone who can figure this out :)
https://pastebin.com/p1fwuuLt

Comment: what is the problem can you explain it a bit more.

Comment: You shouldn't be showing us your entire navbar. Create a minimal example of the icon problem here in a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need more practice in css, specifically in how selectors work.
Either mark each li with a class you can select or use nth-child selector on the li (not recommended).

```css
#nav_bar {
  background: #181818;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 3;
  min-height: 500px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#nav_bar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.lang {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.lang a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #A1A1A1;
}

.lang a:hover,
.lang a.active {
  color: #08ccfd;
}

.logo {
  background: #070707;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px auto;
  width: 24px;
  height: auto;
}

#nav_bar nav {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav_bar nav a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav_bar nav a i {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#nav_bar nav a:hover i {
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav_bar nav a.active,
#nav_bar nav a:hover {
  color: #08ccfd;
}

#nav_bar nav a:after {
  content: '';
  font-size: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#nav_bar nav li:nth-child(1) a:after {
  content: 'HOME';
}

#nav_bar nav li:nth-child(2) a:after {
  content: 'ABOUT';
}

#nav_bar nav li:nth-child(3) a:after {
  content: 'SKILLS';
}

#nav_bar nav li:nth-child(4) a:after {
  content: 'MY WORK';
}

#nav_bar nav li:nth-child(5) a:after {
  content: 'CONTACT';
}

#nav_bar nav.pl a:first-child:after {
  content: 'START';
}

#nav_bar nav.pl a:first-child+a:after {
  content: 'O MNIE';
}

#nav_bar nav.pl a:first-child+a+a:after {
  content: 'SKILSY';
}

#nav_bar nav.pl a:first-child+a+a+a:after {
  content: 'PORTFOLIO';
}

#nav_bar nav.pl a:first-child+a+a+a+a:after {
  content: 'KONTAKT';
}

#nav_bar nav a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="nav_bar">

  <nav class=" en">
    <ul>
      <li><a rel="index" href="input.url" class="home-link active"><i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a rel="about" href="input.url" class=""><i class="fas fa-user-alt fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li>
        <a rel="skills" href="input.url" class=""><i class="fas fa-cog fa-2x"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a rel="gallery" href="input.url" class=""><i class="fas fa-eye fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a rel="contact" href="input.url" class=""><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
```